# How to avoid flipped looking normals when baking them?

Tags: uv, normals, baking, normal-map

So I ran into this the second time now. The normals on the model flip randomly despite the faces are facing outwards. In this case it happens at the uv seam of the model but other times it seemed completely random. What's causing this?
[image: flippednormals]

It all comes dow to marked seams? Or is there something else in the works which I don't understand?
Please help.

Comment: hello, please pack the image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use color space: `Non-Color`  for the normal map in the ImageTexture node, not sRGB. Classic mistake ;-)

Comment: Ohh but I cannot change the color space, as you can see under there it's gray. But I will figure it out I probably need to save the picture or something.

Comment: That's probably because there is another ImageTexture node (for baking?) that uses the image. In your screenshot, you see the number "2" which indicates there are 2 "users". Click on it to make a new instance. Then you should be able to change the color space.

Comment: Yes, I added the texture to both objects. Anyways I needed to save it and now it works, Thanks!

Comment: I've just created an account to appreciate the upper guy, get into the point immediately